# Java Arraylist.Using Generics and Wildcards to create a reusable method

Tags: java, android

I am creating a reusable method that returns an array-list.

Here's what i am trying to achieve.

```
public List<?> getReusable(String method) {

    List<?> mResuableList = new ArrayList<>();

    switch (method) {
    case METHOD_1:
        mResuableList.add(new TypeOne("TypeOne","TypeOneID"))
        break;
    case METHOD_2:
        mResuableList.add(new TypeTwo("TypeTwo","TypeTwoID",1234,true));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return mResuableList;
}
```

Please tell if i can achieve this.

Comment: Are you trying to add "types" (i.e. classes of) different objects to your `ArrayList`??  You can't do that.  It would seem to me that your `ArrayList` _must_ be of type `T extends Type` where `TypeOne extends Type` and `TypeTwo extends Type` (whatever that `Type` class would be).

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to make the return type typesafe?

Comment: @Thilo Alright Here goes,I created this method to return data that exists in various database tables.So i can use this same method over and over again by changing the arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
public abstract class TypeBase {

}

public class TypeOne extends TypeBase {
    public TypeOne(String val1, String val2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}

public class TypeTwo extends TypeBase {
    public TypeTwo(String val1, String val2, int val3, boolean val4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}

public <T extends TypeBase> List<T> getReusable(int method) {
    List<T> mResuableList = new ArrayList<T>();
    switch (method) {
    case 1:
        mResuableList.add((T) new TypeOne("TypeOne", "TypeOneID"));
        break;
    case 2:
        mResuableList.add((T) new TypeTwo("TypeTwo", "TypeTwoID", 1234, true));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return mResuableList;
}

public class UsingClass{
    public void callReusable(){
        List<TypeOne> lstOne = getReusable(1);
        List<TypeTwo> lstTwo = getReusable(2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your List to be able to hold objects of types `TypeOne` and `TypeTwo` I would create an interface and have the two classes implement it:

```
public interface Interface {}

public class TypeOne implements Interface {/*class specifications here*/}

public class TypeTwo implements Interface {/*class specifications here*/}
```

Then you can add them both to your `List<Interface>`:

```
List<Interface> mResuableList = new ArrayList<>();
mResuableList.add(new TypeOne("TypeOne","TypeOneID"));
mResuableList.add(new TypeTwo("TypeTwo","TypeTwoID",1234,true));
```

Answer (score 1):

`List<?> mResuableList = new ArrayList<>();`

replace above line of code with

`List<Object> mResuableList = new ArrayList<>();`

This will serve your purpose.

[You can insert an Object, or any subtype of Object, into a List. But you can only insert null into a List.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html)

Note: Better programming practice is to be more specific.